# upload data into zookeeper using ansible

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ansible

I am new to ansible. I have seen examples of how to start zookeeper and exhibitor using ansible. but I am not sure if we can upload data(bulk or simple node) to zookeeper using ansible. If possible, please suggest an example for same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by "can upload data". Can you describe the manual steps that you are trying to ansibleized? Is it just a matter of copying files from one host to another?